# showing element out of scroll area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a chosen drop down in a box. Box has fixed height and width. Whenever I select a value from dropdown the box shows scroll bars. I want to show the options of dropdown box above the box. How can I do it?

check my code at http://jsfiddle.net/tqHNs/

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <select id="sel" style="width: 100px;">
        <option value="1">Val-1</option>
        <option value="1">Val-1</option>
        <option value="1">Val-1</option>
        <option value="1">Val-1</option>
        <option value="1">Val-1</option>
        <option value="1">Val-1</option>
        <option value="1">Val-1</option>
        <option value="1">Val-1</option>
        <option value="1">Val-1</option>
        <option value="1">Val-1</option>
        <option value="1">Val-1</option>
        <option value="1">Val-1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the solution i posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule to you CSS or change the CSS rules in the chosen.CSS file

```
.chosen-container{
    position:absolute !important;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/tqHNs/2/)

Comment: this created another issue, please chk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218702/jquery-chosen-handling-overlapping-issue-with-position-absolute

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: scroll` is forcing the dropdown to stay inside of the div.

Remove the overflow style and it will expand outside of the box.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mn6yA/)

Comment: Box is of fixed width/height, Can use overflow: auto or scroll only

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your overflow property or something.Its because of your jquery.

**Result**

[image]