# jquery chosen handling overlapping issue with position absolute

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I have a fixed container in which I am showing some form elements and also a select element stylized with jquery chosen. The problem is I need to show the drop-down area of chosen above the container, for this I need to set `.chosen-container {position: absolute}` but after setting it to absolute when the fixed area is scrolled  the chosen remained at fixed location. How to fix it?

css code:

```
#fixed {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.chosen-container {
    position: absolute;
}
.txt {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

html code:

```
<div id="fixed">
    <input class="txt" type="text" value="" />
    <input class="txt" type="text" value="" />
    <input class="txt" type="text" value="" />
<select class="chos" style="width: 165px">
    <option value="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="4">Val 4</option>
    <option value="5">Val 5</option>
    <option value="6">Val 6</option>
    <option value="7">Val 7</option>
</select>
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite sure if your fiddle matches the code in your question...

Comment: add `top:0;` property in `.chosen-container` class. check this fiddle update [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/umcc9/1/)

Comment: @coure2011, I got little time to check the issue however check this fiddle. its buggy bcos it wont work if the user doesnt make a selection in the dropdown. but you can work out the logic and apply it http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/umcc9/3/

Comment: I really like your idea! I think we can achieve the required behavior using approach. Let me try